# SSRS Border on Nested Row Group

Tags: sql, reporting-services, border, ssrs-grouping

I am creating an **SSRS2012** report.

I have a matrix with static columns and nested row groups. I would like to add a top and bottom border on my rows based on the parent group. The matrix looks as follows:

```
[ProcessCell] | [Name]  | [Field]|
```

My groups are: `ProcessCell1 (parent) - Name (child)`

I am currently using standard formatting to get `[ProcessCell]`'s borders and it works. I am using an expression (found in another article) for `[Name]`'s borders and it works, however the expression does not work for the `[Field]` box. The expression is as follows:

```
=IIf(Fields!ProcessCell.Value = Previous(Fields!ProcessCell.Value, "Name") OR Not(Fields!ProcessCell.Value = First(Fields!ProcessCell.Value, "Name")), "Light Gray", "Black")
```

I have tried changing the scopes of previous and first but it did not work.

The error I am getting is "BorderColor expression for the text box '`Field`' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function"

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem today (well with a `Tablix`, not a matrix, and in SSRS 2008 R2). I couldn't get the `Previous()` function to work properly and not throw the same "BorderStyle expression for the textbox..." error that you're seeing.

What I did instead was add a new field to my Dataset that uses the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic SQL function to categorize my results. The relevant fields in my report were UserName, ReportName, and DatetimeRun (yes, this was a report on report usage). I wanted borders to appear between each unique combination of UserName and ReportName, so I added this field to my dataset:

```
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by UserName,ReportName order by UserName,ReportName)
as RowNum
```

which for each unique combination of UserName and ReportName (the fields in the `Partition by` portion), starts at 1 and sequentially numbers the rows returned.

Back in my BorderStyle/Top expression, instead of using `Previous()` I used this:

```
=iif(Fields!RowNum.Value = 1,"Solid","None")
```

to display a border only at the beginning of a new UserName/ReportName combination.

Hope this helps!